# Flash is Not Working in iPhone 6S with iOS 11.2.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avcapturedevice

When I'm running the app in iPhone 6S with iOS 11.2.2. The Flash is not working. Toggle button is working fine i.e., On/Off. But, Flash is not coming when the toggle is On.

```
- (void)toggleFlash{
        NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
        for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices){
            if (device.flashAvailable) {
                if (flashOn){
                    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
                    [device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                    [device unlockForConfiguration];
                }
                else{
                    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
                    [device isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                    [device unlockForConfiguration];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Done with the debugging.. It's working fine. But, Issue with Flash.
Anyone Working on this issue. Please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks whether torch mode is available (`isTorchModeSupported`) but never turns on the torch. You can use `setTorchModeOn` for that,

Comment: I'm using MACaptureSession., setTorchMode is not visible on MACaptureSession.

Comment: - (void)toggleFlash
{
    if (flashIsOn)
    {
        flashIsOn = NO;
        [_captureManager setFlashOn:NO];
        [_flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-off-button"]];
        _flashButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Enable Camera Flash";
        [self storeFlashSettingWithBool:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        flashIsOn = YES;
        [_captureManager setFlashOn:YES];
        [_flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-on-button"]];
        _flashButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Disable Camera Flash";
        [self storeFlashSettingWithBool:YES];
    }
}

Comment: This is the code for Torchmode i writen in another class.

Comment: In your code the variable `device` is of type `AVCaptureDevice`, which definitely has that method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624609-settorchmodeon